# What is the difference between a loss of control and an upset?

Tags: flight-controls, accidents

What is the difference between a loss of control and an upset? From what I have read, first, an upset occurs, which leads to a loss of control (LOC). But, when can one say that the upset has been transformed into a LOC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Aircraft upset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_upset)

> is a dangerous condition in aircraft operations in
>   which the flight attitude or airspeed of an aircraft is outside the
>   normal bounds of operation for which it is designed. This may result
>   in the loss of control (LOC) of the aircraft, and sometimes the total
>   loss of the aircraft itself.

[Loss of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_control_(aeronautics)#Notable_accidents)

> is the unintended departure of
>   an aircraft from controlled flight, and is a significant factor in
>   several aviation accidents worldwide and the leading cause of jet
>   fatalities worldwide. Loss of control may be the result of
>   mechanical failure, external disturbances, aircraft upset conditions,
>   or inappropriate crew actions or responses.

TL;DR:

- Upset occurs when attitude and/or airspeed are outside of the boundaries where the aircraft is controllable.
- Upset is one of many possible causes for loss of control.

Comment: Or in short: upset = you're inverted (could be fun in certain aircraft), loss of control = you can't get back upright.

Comment: @Jan, upset is not inverted, and inverted is not an upset in aircraft that are designed for it.